# Continualy reasking for wifi password

Tags: wireless

I am on Ubuntu 14.04

When I try to connect to the wifi it promts for password and then it fails and ask for the password again

Password is correct as I have several other devices connected to the same wifi without issues

I have restart network-manager, I have "all users may connect to this network" checked and tried with it unchecked. I have deleted and re-added the connection several times. I have tried my netgear usb wifi adapter as well as the internal one so I don't think it is that. I have turned the network adapter power saver off (though this didn't change as it was already turned off on account I was using power adapter)

I ran a wireless-info script but I can't seem to add attachments to this forum

(I also tried using the latest linux-mint but this had the same issue)

Comment: updated to ubuntu 15 and it hasn't happened since